# not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: php, xml, soap

I got this from a Soap client request:

> Exception: SoapFault exception:
>   [soap:Client] Server was unable to
>   read request. ---> There is an error
>   in XML document (2, 273). ---> The
>   string '2010-5-24' is not a valid
>   AllXsd value. in /path/filinet.php:21
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
>   SoapClient->__call('SubIdDetailsByO...',
>   Array) #1 /path/filinet.php(21):
>   SoapClient->SubIdDetailsByOfferId(Array) #2 {main}

Seems like I am sending an incorrect value, how do I format my value in an AllXsd in php?

Here is my code:

```
<?php       
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : date("Y-m-d");
$end = isset($_GET['end']) ? $_GET['end'] : date("Y-m-d");

//define parameter array
$param = array('userName'=>'user', 'password'=>'pass', 'startDate' => $start, 'endDate' => $end, 'promotionId' => '');

//Get wsdl path
$serverPath = "https://webservices.filinet.com/affiliate/reports.asmx?WSDL";

 //Declare Soap client
 $client = new SoapClient($serverPath);
 try {
        //make the call
        $result = $client->SubIdDetailsByOfferId($param);
        //If error found display error
        if(isset($fault))
        {
            echo "Error: ". $fault;
        }
        //If no error display response
        else
        {
            //Used to display raw XML in the Web Browser
            header("Content-Type: text/xml;");
            //SubIdDetailsResult = XML results
            echo $result->SubIdDetailsByOfferIdResult;
        }
    }
    catch(SoapFault $ex) {
        echo "<b>Exception:</b> ". $ex;
    }
unset($client);
?>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

AllXsd values look something like this IIRC

> 2010-05-24T18:13:00

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the ISO 8601 date format `date('c', strtotime($my_date));`

> http://php.net/date

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the date format of either $start or $end. Instead of just grabbing the data from the query string with $_GET and sending it over, you need to do some integrity checking to make sure that the date matches the required format

```
2010-05-24T13:46:00
```

Instead of using date("Y-m-d") try using:

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d") . 'T' . date("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
// get the date
$startDate = date("Y-m-d") . 'T' . date("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cut to the chase and use

```
date('c');
```