# C# error web services

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Please help in this error. System.FormatException: The string '2013-08-30 20:50:45' is not a valid AllXsd value.

I just used the basic add web service reference in vs2010

```
var thirdPartyApi = new ThirdPartyApi();
User user = thirdPartyApi.getUser(id, apiKey);
```

the error occurred in property name "DateJoined" System.DateTime object

I dont have an access to the API to edit it and noted that API is working properly in SoapUI tool.

May be any other way or settings to add the web services to support non standard date format.

Thank you for advance

Comment: Do you set this DateTime somewhere?

Comment: No. The code "DateJoined" System.DateTime is in ThirdPartyApi and I cant do anything about this.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the external API. As for the AIIXsd format, there is some more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899366/2416958 maby you can use it to set a value somewhere :|

Comment: I did not set it to any of my code since the API return an error. Thanks for the link. actually I almost read all links in top 5 pages in google including that page and most of the comments is the date format is not standard. But my concern is how/why the SoupUI tool manage it properly.

Comment: Do you get the error on the first line? Or on the second?

Comment: The error occurred in second line. im sure I added the WebService properly because other method like thirdPartyApi.getCurrency() and thirdPartyApi.getCountry() is working properly.

Comment: Is "DateJoined" a property of the ThirdPartyApi?

Comment: yes "DateJoined" is a property of the ThirdPartyApi.

Comment: Hmm.. since it is a DateTime it's not possible to parse it wrong. You can try to set it first, maybe that helps. DateTime parsing can be CultureInfo dependent, you'll could play a bit with that. Otherwise I am blank. Sorry about that.